# Memory efficient classifiers in R for extremely wide and not too long training set

Tags: r, classification, regression, correlation, random-forest

Training data set is is extremely wide (about 200K features) and very short (in hundreds). Obviously the data set occupies a lot of memory but R reads it without problems.

Then I trained Random Forest classifier and it ran out of memory on it. So I am switching to simpler classifier like Naive Bayes. NB resulted in out of memory too.

Generally, what are most memory efficient classifiers? I suspect that logistic regression and Naive Bayes should make the list...

**UPD:**

I ended up using feature reduction methods before using random forest. Package [caret](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/index.html) can help but not with initial number of variables in my case.

Feature reductions used:

- variance threshold filter (removed features with variance below threshold);
- correlation between feature and predicted values: removed features with low correlation;
- feature pair-wise correlations: removing high pair-wise correlation features.

Comment: How hard did you try to get the random forest to run efficiently in R? Not all of the default settings are advisable with data like yours.

Comment: To add to what joran said, I would recommend messing around with the following options in your `randomForest(x, y,...)` formula:   `ntree`, `mtry`, `nodesize`, `maxnodes`.  All of those will have an effect on the build speed of your random forest.  Judging by your brief description of the dataset, I would say you might want to try decreasing `mtry` and increasing `nodesize` and `maxnodes`.

Comment: I indeed appreciate help on random forest but I still hope to see  other classifier suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most memory efficient algorithms are the ones based on [online learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) (which don't load the whole dataset in memory, but learn one instance at a time) and [feature hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing), also called the hashing trick (which can turn arbitrarily large feature vectors to a predefined/fixed size by using hashing). Logistic regression and linear SVM both have online learning and feature hashing based implementations (which boils down to optimizing for logistic loss or hinge loss, respectively).

I don't know of an implementation in R (there might be, just don't know the R library well engouh), but a very solid and widely used learner that makes use of these techniques is [Vowpal Wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki). They're also implemented in [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).

Answer (score 2):

The `glmnet` package can handle sparse matrices and will be more memory efficient than an ensemble, but still offer variable selection (via lasso/elastic net).  Code might look like this:

```
library(glmnet)
df <- read.csv() #data
X <- sparse.model.matrix( ~ . - y, df) #Matrix with all variables in df except the y variable.
y <- df$y
model <- cv.glmnet(X, y, nfolds = 10, family='binomial' )
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~caruana/ctp/ct.papers/caruana.icml06.pdf) from the Cornell CS department that compares the efficacy of different classifiers.  It does not get into speed, but it goes over the predictive power of pretty much every classification algorithm widely in use today.  The fastest ones will be the algorithms that are *not* ensemble learning classifiers.  Any algorithm that builds multiple models and averages the results will inherently take longer.  However, as can be seen in Table 2 on pg. 5, the most effective classifiers are the ensemble techniques.  If you want to build the model as fast as possible, then you should probably just use a single decision tree or a logistic regression.  Otherwise, you should spend some time getting to know an ensemble learning technique and figure out how to optimize the speed of that particular algorithm.  I've gotten good results parallelizing my random forests using a technique similar to [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-random-forests-using-foreach/).

**Edit to more closely address your memory concerns:**  Memory usage is less about *which* algorithm you choose than it is about how you use that algorithm.  Assuming you used the default random forest call for your original model, you would have built 500 decision trees, each one having ~450 predictor variables and as many terminal nodes as you have data points in the sample.  This will take up a ton of memory.  The point I am trying to make is that you can adjust any of these classification models to take up less memory and run more efficiently in R.  As mentioned before, however, the non-ensemble techniques (logistic regression, naive bayes, CHAID/CART/etc decision trees) will use the least memory by default.

Comment: I never asked about neither classifers' general efficiency nor about speed - only about memory efficiency in R. I do have decent idea about ensemble classifiers among others. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: I worded my answer poorly, but in my experience, speed issues boil down to memory issues in model building.  When you built your random forest on 200+ predictor variables without changing any of the default options, you essentially built 500 models (which is the default number of trees, as can be seen [on p. 17 of the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf)).  These models were all stored in memory, and then averaged to give you the final output.  Any of these techniques can be memory hogs if you aren't careful with your parameters...

Comment: make that "200k+ predictor variables"